# Google Maps setMyLocationEnabled(true) takes long to show current location

Tags: android, google-maps, android-gps

I am using [setMyLocationEnabled(true)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)) and MapView shows my location after some time.. But sometimes it takes more than 10 sec. On the other hand, calling `mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()` returns location immediatelly and I can show a marker of my current location.

Why doesn't the blue dot show immediatelly? I don't want to have an additional marker.

Answer (score 1):

`getLastLocation()` is a cached location and might not be your actual location.

maps does not show your location immediately because it needs time to lock on to a GPS satellite. You would probably see the same results if you used the fused client to listen for location changes

Comment: In the old times I remember this "blue dot" had a shade around it, representing the location confidence. Is it possible to get this behavior back, using some kind of criteria?

Comment: It still does looking at the documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location

Comment: Interesting. Testing on a real device suggests otherwise (with default settings).